# Check for reverse pair repetition in two arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have two arrays as follows:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
b = [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4]
```

All the possible pairs these two arrays can form are `(a[0],b[0]),(a[1],b[1]),(a[2],b[2]),(a[3],b[3]),...,(a[11],b[11])`. The two arrays have same length and a pair is formed between same indices.
The problem is to check that how many pairs are there who have a reverse pair present for them.
For example, in the arrays I provided above the pairs `(a[1],b[1])` and `(a[3],b[3])` form one reverse pair because `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` are reverse of each other. Similarly `(a[2],b[2])` forms a reverse pair with `(a[10],b[10])`. Can someone guide me how to count the total number of reverse pairs that exist between two arrays?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and how it went wrong.

Comment: I can't think of the logic. I am not asking for code, just provide me with a logic. Many thanks.

Comment: zip(a, b) gives you all the pairs, so perhaps compare zip(a, b) to zip(b, a) ?

Comment: Well, you can make a reversed pair of original pairs, add to original list of pairs, and count if you have duplicates. It is not the most efficient way, but at least should give you a start

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndersThirsgaardRasmussen. zip is the function I was looking for. I did not know how to write an array with multiple values at each element.

Comment: You could simply reverse by switching the position of the items in your list `for item in c: rev = (item[-1],item[0])`

Comment: @UsamaTahir for your example, what would the total count be?

Comment: @NickParsons for my example the total count is 5. The pairs are ```(a[1],b[1]) , (a[3],b[3])```, ```(a[2],b[2]) , (a[10],b[10])```, ```(a[4],b[4]) , (a[5],b[5])``` ,```(a[7],b[7]) , (a[8],b[8])``` and ```(a[9],b[9]) , (a[11],b[11])```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
B = [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4]

for pair in zip(A,B):

    rpair = pair[::-1]

    print(pair,rpair)
```

**Result:**

```
(1, 1) (1, 1)
(1, 2) (2, 1)
(1, 5) (5, 1)
(2, 1) (1, 2)
(2, 3) (3, 2)
(3, 2) (2, 3)
(3, 3) (3, 3)
(3, 4) (4, 3)
(4, 3) (3, 4)
(4, 5) (5, 4)
(5, 1) (1, 5)
(5, 4) (4, 5)

A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
B = [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4]

for pair in zip(A,B):

    rpair = pair[::-1]

    if pair[0] == rpair[1] and pair[1] == rpair[0]:

        print(pair,rev_pair)
```

**Result**

```
(1, 1) (4, 5)
(1, 2) (4, 5)
(1, 5) (4, 5)
(2, 1) (4, 5)
(2, 3) (4, 5)
(3, 2) (4, 5)
(3, 3) (4, 5)
(3, 4) (4, 5)
(4, 3) (4, 5)
(4, 5) (4, 5)
(5, 1) (4, 5)
(5, 4) (4, 5)
```

**Final**

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
B = [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4]

n = 0
for pair in zip(A,B):

    rpair = pair[::-1]

    if pair[0] == rpair[1] and pair[1] == rpair[0]:
        n = n + 1
print('total pairs : {}'.format(n))
```

**Result**

```
total pairs : 12
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty vague question.
Do you want to count `+1` if a single reverse pair is present, or `+n` if n reverse of `(a[i], b[i])` is found in the arrays?
How about only counting reverse pairs a single time?
Should `(1, 1)` be counted as a reverse pair, or not?

For the future, perhaps show the answer you expect for your simple test-system.

I would expect that your test-system should give `n=12` reverse pairs, assuming you only count reverse pair a single time in the calculation.

Just a simple implementation that is easy to read:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
B = [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4]

n = 0
pairs = [pair for pair in zip(A, B)]
for rev_pair in zip(B, A):
    if rev_pair in pairs:
        n += 1
```

I'm sure a much faster implementation could be made..

Comment: You could extract `zip(A, B)` to a variable outside because currently this is called many times.